# When configuring firewalls do the protocols allowed need 2 way communication?

Tags: firewall

For example if I were configuring my PC to browse the web over HTTP and I have denied all inbound and outbound  requests and responses, would I need to only open port 80 to outbound requests or would I need to open port 80 to outbound and inbound requests?

Comment: Depends on your firewall.  Some are smart enough to be able to match the flow of traffic, and allow stuff back in that corresponds to the stuff sent out.

Comment: @Tom O'Connor - Can you elaborate?

Comment: read Zoredache's answer about Stateful Firewalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit on the vague side.  There are many different firewall implementations.

On old low-end firewalls (stateless packet filters) you had to write rules to permit or deny the traffic for both directions.  Most firewalls these days are [stateful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall).  If you build your rules the correct way, then you can write a rule to permit the connection to be established, and once it is established everything else will be permitted.  You can still write stateless rules on most stateful firewalls.

A linux iptables based firewall would setup stateful connections like this.  Note I am only have an explicit rule for the incoming connections to the mysql server, the outgoing will be handled by the ESTABLISHED rule.

```
# permit established connections
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# permit incoming requests to a mysql server
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp --destination mysql.server.ip --dport 3306 \
         -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If the firewall you curious about is not Linux based, you will almost certainly have to dig into the docs for that specific firewall.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. I can appreciate the types of firewalls i.e. stateful and stateless however assuming either are being used, I assume based on your answer in its most basic form of communication I would need to allow HTTP for incoming and outgoing. Is that right?